# How to swipe to delete in a table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

***Hello,***

I'm having trouble using the swipe to delete feature with *Swift* specifically, I implemented the following method to my table view but the delete button will not appear when I swipe across the simulator with the pointer. I tried to override the method but I got the following error saying,

- *override can only be specified on class members*

  ```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
          if editingStyle == .Delete {
              // Delete the row from the data source
              Names.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
              Locations.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
              Types.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
              IsVisited.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
              Images.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

           print("Total Item: \(Names.count)")
          for name in Names {
              print(name)
  }
  ```

Comment: Have you made sure that your tableView is not larger than the screen? :)

Comment: I was able to solve this question instead of declaring  variable for each data source property, I defined an `Information` object to save all of the information and a Field and Value `stackview` @user2893289

Comment: Okey great. A suggestion, add your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of declaring variables for each property, I now define a `Information` object to save all of the information. I replace the following variables:

```
var Image = ""
var Name = ""
var Type = ""
var Location = ""
```

with

```
var information: InformationSource!
```

Then I connected the label object from the object library in the prototype cell. I made a label for `Field` and `Value`, the field will hold Image, Name,Type, Location. Value will hold the values of each variable. Then I stacked both Field and Value horizontally

```
// Delete button
        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete",handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

            // Delete the row from the data source
            self.InformationSource.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let block = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Block") { action, index in
        print("Block")
        self.removeObjectAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") { action, index in
        print("Delete")
        self.removeObjectAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    return [delete, block]
}
```

Comment: Please, can you explain what you have done to fix his issue so other users understand your solution more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use existing solutions. https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell It works fine for me.

Check swift implementation here: https://github.com/torryharris/TH-SwipeCell